# How to write a file's name with special character in command line?

Tags: special-characters, command-line-interface, ubuntu-12.04

I've got a file named '-help.txt' in Ubuntu. I know that I should use command like this:

```
> rm ./-help.txt
```

Could anyone give me an url where I can learn systematically on how to deal with the special characters in Ubuntu command line. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try the manpages first:

```
> man rm
```

Undoubtedly, you are using GNU *rm*, and you will find that GNU programs use -- to separate options from arguments, even though using ./ works.

```
> rm -- -help.txt
```

Then, try the GNU info system:

```
> info rm
> info fileutils
```